# Capturing all HTTP POST Requests Including Body with tcpdump

Tags: unix, tcpdump

I want to print all HTTP POST requests including the body of the requests in ASCII to the console with tcpdump. How can I do that?

Comment: Try : tcpdump -c 20 -s 0 -i eth1 -A host 192.168.1.1 and tcp port http

Comment: Using tcpflow : tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 | grep -oE '(GET|POST|HEAD) .* HTTP/1.[01]|Host: .*'

Comment: Or use tshark.  The short answer is, you can't do this easily with TCPDump.